# Facebook Graph API - Get user feed posts with pictures

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the Javascript SDK, and I'm currently able to successfully have a user log into my app using their Facebook and get posts using /me/feed. However, those posts only seem to have the fields: message, story, created_time, and id. How can I get the pictures, links etc associated with these posts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to ask for the Post fields you want to get:

```
/me/feed?fields=message,xxx,...
```